# Share the same models and database session between Flask and FastAPI application

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I started for developing a project for an IoT application in Flask. This application has an API blueprint which has been growing a lot and now I'm trying to migrate the API to FastAPI. My project follows this structure:

```
api (FastAPI application)
     __init__.py (where I create the FastAPI app)
application (Flask application)
     __init__.py (where I create the Flask app)
models (SQL alchemy models that I want to share between both applications)
wsgi.py (I use multiprocessing to launch to separate processes, one for the Flask App and another for Fast Api)
```

The Flask module is running well and the FastApi one is running too. However, I can't use my models in the FastAPI routers since I'm not initializing the db correctly in this. I need to create something that let me share the session between the FastAPI and Flask modules.

I let you with my `__init__.py` of both modules:

Flask:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()


def create_app():
   """Initialize the core application."""
   app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=False)
   # The following line loads the configurations from Config file
   app.config.from_object('config.DevelopmentConfig')
   db.init_app(app)

   with app.app_context():
      # Import parts of our application
      from application.blueprints.oauth.routes import auth as auth_blueprint
      app.register_blueprint(auth_blueprint)
    
      ....

      db.create_all()
      return app
```

FastAPI:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, APIRouter
from fastapi_sqlalchemy import DBSessionMiddleware  # middleware helper
from fastapi_sqlalchemy import db
from .controllers.system import *


def create_app():
   """Initialize the core application."""
   app = FastAPI(debug=True)

   app.add_middleware(DBSessionMiddleware, db_url="sqlite:///../database.db")

   app.include_router(router=router)

   return app
```

How could I make this work?

Best regards,